# RegEx pattern for comma separated 10 currencies in URI parameter

Tags: java, regex, raml, mulesoft

I need to pass a list of comma separated currencies as URI parameter.

I need a regEx to allow only capital letters in group of three, separated by comma, and that does not allow any white space character.

I tried `((?=\S)[A-Z\s\,]){3,39}+$` regEx

It is working fine for input like: **USD,  ,J**

But it start falling for input like :
**USD,  ,JPY**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
^[A-Z]{3}(?:,[A-Z]{3}){0,9}$
```

This will match 1 upto 10 currencies comma separated

**Explanation:**

```
[A-Z]{3}        # 3 letters
(?:             # start non capture group
    ,           # a comma
    [A-Z]{3}    # 3 letters
){0,9}          # end group, may appear 0 upto 9 times
```

Comment: This regex matches **ABCDEFGHI**, it must force to put a **,** between two currencies

Comment: @AashuY, No, it doesn't match `ABCDEFGHI` , see: https://regex101.com/r/xX4wwU/1

Comment: This one is working fine **^[A-Z]{3}(?:,[A-Z]{3}){0,19}$**

Comment: @AashuY: True, I've forgotten the anchors. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you Toto, i missed starting ^ and end $. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with this RegEx: [A-Z]{3,39}[,]{1,9}

And could you test in : https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: This regex matches `ABCDEFGHIJ,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: Agreed with Toto. It must only allow like **ABC,DEF,GHI,**